# Can you have two different bank accounts in two different countries but with the same bank?

Tags: banking, bank-account

Imagine that I have an account with HSBC in the UK. Would it be possible to open an account in the U.S. with HSBC?

So to speak to have two different bank accounts but with the same bank in two different countries?

Thank you.

Comment: Sure you can - the same way as you can have multiple accounts with the same bank in the same country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Imagine that I have an account with HSBC in the UK. Would it be possible to open an account in the U.S. with HSBC?

An individual can hold accounts with same Banks in different countries. There is no restriction. If one fulfils the criteria, one can open an account.

Depending on geographies and regulations, some banks may actively help you open account in other country if you need so. However in most ordinary situations bank may not help.

In your specific example, if you travel to US, you can submit relevant documentation and open an checking account.